# How do you pass elements from an arraylist index using Parcelable?

Tags: java, android, arrays, parcelable

On a match I need all the elements of an array index passed to another activity.  Here's what I have...

```
    Intent LocationReview = new Intent(v.getContext(), ReviewActivity.class);
     // iterate through array 
    for (int i = 0; i < locationReview.size(); i++) {

int locationID = locationReview.get(i).id;
int currentID = Integer.parseInt(tvId.getText().toString());

          // compare id no. at index i of array
          if ((locationReview.get(i).id == Integer.parseInt(tvId.getText().toString()))) {

          // if match set putExtra array to locationReview.get(i)
              **LocationReview.putParcelableArrayListExtra("locationReview", locationReview.get(i));**
              itemView.getContext().startActivity(LocationReview);
              } else {
                Log.e("VerticalAdapter", "no matcon on locationReview");
               }
           }
```

The if statment compares the `id` element in the locationReview array.  If the element matches the string in the text view I need array index of `i` , and all its elements, added as a pracelable array and added as Extra to my intent.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the solution into several steps:

**Step 1.** Make sure your ArrayList model class implements the *Parcelable* interface.

**Step 2.** Iterate through all elements of *locationReview* array to figure out which its indexes are matching your requirements. You may define another "filtered" ArrayList object in the class and populate it with the items filtered by your *(locationReview.get(i).id == Integer.parseInt(tvId.getText().toString()))* condition.

```
ArrayList<Object> filteredlocationReview = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < locationReview.size(); i++) {

        int locationID = locationReview.get(i).id;
        int currentID = Integer.parseInt(tvId.getText().toString());

        // compare id no. at index i of array
        if ((locationReview.get(i).id == Integer.parseInt(tvId.getText().toString()))) {
            filteredlocationReview.add(locationReview.get(i))
        }
    }
```

**Step 3.** Being out of the loop scope put the filtered Parcelable array through

```
LocationReview.putParcelableArrayListExtra("locationReview", filteredlocationReview);
```

**Step 4.** Start new activity where you need to make use of *getParcelableArrayListExtra* method to get your array.